# Scoping ignore declarations in unison

Tags: sync, unison, ignore

I am using unison to synchronize two computers, and generally I would like to ignore all hidden files except a few. I have a unison preference file (`default.prf`) that looks as follows:

```
# Unison preferences file

# keep time stamps
times = true
auto = true

ignore = Name .*

path = Documents
path = .hgrc
path = .vimrc
```

Even though I'd like most hidden files to be ignore, I'd like `.hgrc` and `.vimrc` to be synced between the two computers. However, with the setup above they are ignored too. How can I fix the problem of syncing them?

Answer (score 3):

According to http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#prefs, "ignorenot" may be useful here.

> This preference overrides the preference ignore. It gives a list of
>   patterns (in the same format as ignore) for paths that should
>   definitely not be ignored, whether or not they happen to match one of
>   the ignore patterns.

I'm not an experienced Unison user, so I don't know if the following caveat applies here:

> Note that the semantics of ignore and ignorenot is a little
>   counter-intuitive. When detecting updates, Unison examines paths in
>   depth-first order, starting from the roots of the replicas and working
>   downwards. Before examining each path, it checks whether it matches
>   ignore and does not match ignorenot; in this case it skips this path
>   and all its descendants. This means that, if some parent of a given
>   path matches an ignore pattern, then it will be skipped even if the
>   path itself matches an ignorenot pattern. In particular, putting
>   ignore = Path * in your profile and then using ignorenot to select
>   particular paths to be synchronized will not work. Instead, you should
>   use the path preference to choose particular paths to synchronize.

I realize this comes more than a month after your question. Still, I hope it's useful.